# MongoDB/Java: Type safety in DBObjects

Tags: java, mongodb, types, deserialization

I have a field in a MongoDB document that stores an arbitrarily-large number.  When I retrieve it as a DBObject (Java driver for MongoDB), I sometimes run into a ClassCastException:

```
DBObject obj = collection.findOne();
long val = (Long)(o.get("numericVal"));
```

If the value stored in `numericVal` is, say, 1234567890, the cast to Long succeeds.  If it is, say, 12345, DBObject.get() returns a Double, and the cast fails.

How can I ensure type safety when deserializing MongoDB DBObjects?

Comment: are you positive the value is `12345`? Is there some way with mongo to look at the raw value - does it have a JSON representation?

Comment: i entered it via the shell as 12345, but when i print it in the shell it appears as 12345.0.  obviously that's an issue on the parser (java driver) side, but i don't know how it happened on the mongo side in the first place.  that said, i'd like to know how to maintain type safety in general with the java driver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can avoid the ClassCastException by using the type safe getLong( String key ) rather than cast (Long) and hope that autoboxing does the right thing to get you down to little 'l' long.

http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.8.0/org/bson/BasicBSONObject.html#getLong(java.lang.String)

```
DBObject obj = collection.findOne();
long val = o.getLong("numericVal");
```

I too am skeptical of the 12345 becoming Double.  There is something else going on here.

Comment: didn't see the type-safe getters in BasicBSONObject because i was looking at the docs for the interface BSONObject instead.  thanks for pointing that out.  (was looking for an example that should show how to deserialize mongo objects with the java driver but couldn't find anything!)  however, yes, there is definitely something else going on here...entering 1234567890 for `numericVal` (in the shell) turns up as 1.234567890E9 in the eclipse debugger, which also comes out as a Double.  will report back shortly...

Comment: `getLong()` worked great.  dunno what was up with the type conversion between the shell and the driver, but now i don't care ;)

Answer (score 4):

In general I noticed that numeric values are inserted as double using the shell (or sometimes using other languages)

So for example :

```
db.dummycollection.update({"mykey" : 100}, { $set : { "millisecage" : 30000000 }})
```

inserts a double value (30000000.0)
but

```
db.dummycollection.update({"mykey" : 100}, { $set : { "millisecage" : NumberLong(30000000) }})
```

inserts the correct value in the collection

So if you are in doubt avoid this kind of casting or you can do something like :

```
Long myValue = ((Number) obj.get("yourkey")).longValue();
```